# JSON document fails validation on JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Below Json schema and Json Document both are valid json.
Its just that I am unable to get valid Json document in relation to json schema.

I get error saying: **should NOT have additional properties**

## Json Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Movies Schema",
  "description": "Movies schema containing ratings and genres",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "release_date": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "video": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "IMDBURL": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "genres": {
        "type": "array"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "id",
      "title",
      "release_date",
      "video",
      "IMDBURL",
      "genres"
    ]
  },
  "users": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "user_id": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "ratings": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "timestamps": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "user_id",
      "ratings",
      "timestamps"
    ]
  }
}
```

## JSON Document

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Kung Fu Panda",
    "release_date": "01-01-2001",
    "video": "",
    "IMDBURL": "link.com",
    "genres": [
      "abc",
      "def"
    ],
    "users": {
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `"users"` property is missing from the schema, therefore it is an additional property, so it violates the `"additionalProperties": false` setting.

If you define the `"users"` property in the schema then your document will be valid.

Comment: Please check it does exist, scroll at the bottom.

Comment: in your JSON Object, "user" is part of the "movie" so in your schema, you must add "user" as a field in your movie schema

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the location of additionalProperties.
because the user is of type array with lots of object. The properties of an item is suppose to have additionalProperties not the wrapper "users":{} but the "item":{}

## Solution

**Json Schema**

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "release_date": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "video": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "IMDBURL": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "genres": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "users": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "user_id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "ratings": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "timestamps": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "user_id",
            "ratings",
            "timestamps"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "id",
      "title",
      "release_date",
      "video",
      "IMDBURL",
      "genres",
      "users"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Json Document**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Kung Fu Panda",
    "release_date": "01-01-2000",
    "video": "",
    "IMDBURL": "link.com",
    "genres": [
      "abc",
      "def"
    ],
    "users": [{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    },
{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    },
{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    },
{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    }]
  },
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Kung Fu Panda",
    "release_date": "01-01-2000",
    "video": "",
    "IMDBURL": "link.com",
    "genres": [
      "abc",
      "def"
    ],
    "users": [{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    },
{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    },
{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    },
{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    }]
  },
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Kung Fu Panda",
    "release_date": "01-01-2000",
    "video": "",
    "IMDBURL": "link.com",
    "genres": [
      "abc",
      "def"
    ],
    "users": [{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    },
{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    },
{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    },
{
      "user_id": 2,
      "ratings": 3,
      "timestamps": "2342478"
    }]
  }
]
```